# Does anyone use Netem anymore? Alternatives?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ip, utilities

When simulating an IP network you can use Linux built-in network emulator [Netem.](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem) Together with bridge-utils of course. Simulating packet drop, duplicate packets, jitter et cetera.

Is anyone using this tool anymore or is there more efficient ways to simulate packet distributed networks?

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this...